# My emit doesnt work, I cant send any data to parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

This is my code - child:

```
<a-camp :camp="camp.name" @click="$emit('camp-selected', camp)" />
```

```
export default {
    emits: ['camp-selected'],
...
```

parent:

```
<a-camp-select @camp-selected="campSelected(camp)"></a-camp-select>
```

When I try emit without -camp- parameter it works, I can console log test, but when I add -camp-, I  cant get it to parent, I also try console log camp in child component and it works. So there is problem somewhere in the middle. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mention the parameter when you set the handler for the emitted event <del>`@camp-selected="campSelected(camp)"`</del>:

```html
<a-camp-select @camp-selected="campSelected">
```

you've to mention it inside the method definition:

```js
methods:{
  campSelected(camp){
    //use camp here 
  }
}
```

Comment: and can I use both - emit handler and some other click event on the same component?

Comment: Yes you could use native events like click or other emitted events

Comment: `<a-students
 :student="student"
 :is-active="index == selectedStudent"
 @click="selectedStudent = index"
 @delete-student="onDeleteStudent"
></a-students>`

Comment: I have component like this and there is also problem with emit

Comment: what's the issue?